# Laravel 4.2 : File in a form not working

Tags: php, forms, file-upload, laravel, laravel-4

I have a problem getting a file from a form with Laravel 4.2. I have my form declared like this :

```
{{ Form::open(array('url' => 'app/add-file', 'files' => true)) }}

            {{ Form::file('file')}}

<button type="submit">Confirmer</button>

            {{ Form::close() }}
```

And I only try to show the result in the controller at the moment. But the array is empty.

```
return var_dump(Input::file());
```

When I analyzed the POST request in chrome, i see that the content type in the headers is

> Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8

Maybe it is the problem, but my form is well declared with enctype

> multipart/form-data

Any idea ?

Thanks

Comment: I forgot to mention that I tried to do a simple form without Laravel and it's working, so it is not mamp.

Comment: Did you try writing all the HTML markup instead of leveraging it to Laravel's `Form` class? Just so you can find out where your problem is.

Comment: @KA_lin the docs do mention it as `Input::file()`: http://laravel.com/docs/requests#files

Comment: Oh, it seems he forgot to put the name of the field, though... Edit: Nvm, apparently, when called without any key, `Input::file()` should return all files...

Comment: Yes I tried to write it in HTML, but it is the same problem

Comment: How big is the file? Is it lower than upload_max_filesize?

Answer (score 1):

I found the problem. I was using also jquery mobile and there was the problem. The ajax must be disabled for the form otherwise it is not working with files. I did that

```
{{ Form::open(array('url' => 'app/add-expense', 'files' => true, 'data-ajax' => 'false')) }}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem a few days ago. My file upload was working perfectly and all a sudden my form was not able to upload anymore, I was using Laravel 4.1.*. I wanted to install a package with composer and it require Laravel 4.2.* so i changed the version to suit the package. After that my file upload wasnt working anymore. I newer thought laravel 4.2 was the problem until i uploaded it to my web server and started getting trait issues from the Illuminate class. My local server was running php 5.5.11 and the web server was 5.3.

In short the Laravel 4.2.* works file php 5.5.*. Dont be quick to jump most hosting servers are not running on php 5.4.*. I downgraded to 4.1.*. I didnt change anything and my code was running perfect again.

Install version 4.1 and you would be perfect. My solution was to install laravel 4.1 to a new folder and moved all my codes into it. The User.php controller has that traits if you are using 4.2. So you would need to forget moving User.php, the 4.1 User controller is perfect.

Installing laravel 4.1 was another problem so i did this

```
composer create-project laravel/laravel:4.1.* project_name
```

That's it, should work for you i suppose